# Where to find a Placename ID for Tennengebirge for use in GML?

Tags: gml, inspire

I am new to GML and trying to create an Instance file - I need the ID for Tennengebirge but I am not sure how to find the Inspire ID for this Protected Site?

Answer (score 1):

The basis for your IDs should be an identifier coming from the system where your original data is currently managed. This could be an ID assigned by a database or any other unique identifier that is part of the data and will not change.

If you don't have such an identifier in the original data, you should consider extending your data with an identifier, to ensure that you have reproducable identifiers when transforming your data to INSPIRE.

The INSPIRE ID consists of multiple parts:

- the **localId** which should be the identifier from your original object if possible
- the **namespace** which is a URI that should identify you as a data provider and the data set - in each member state the namespace should be registered in and refer to the respective national registry (e.g. [GDI-DE registry](https://registry.gdi-de.org/) in Germany)
- the **versionId** which is optional and should only be used if you are actually managing different versions of the same object (and have the version information available)

This being said, the procedures of how namespaces are registered are often not clear yet in member states, or the national registry is not available yet. Thus an approach that many people use right now is using a placeholder for the namespace, until the correct namespace is available.

I recommend that you take a detailed look at the INSPIRE data specification for Protected Sites and other documents that can be found on the INSPIRE website for more information.